# error in pywinauto while running the code python3.7 and pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

---

```
Exception ignored in: 0x0000021241E77168>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line >170, in del self.CleanUp()
 File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line >147, in CleanUp self.CheckGuardSignature()
 File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line >286, in CheckGuardSignature c_void_p(self.mem_address + self.size),
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

 Exception ignored in: 0x0000021241E77168>
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line >170, in del self.CleanUp()
 File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line >147, in CleanUp self.CheckGuardSignature()
 File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line >286, in CheckGuardSignature c_void_p(self.mem_address + self.size),
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Warning (from warnings module): File ".\QuickHeal.py", line 12 appl['Dialog']['Edit'].SetText(r"\10.10.93.167\QHUpdates")
 DeprecationWarning: Method .SetEditText() is deprecated, use .set_edit_text() >instead.
 Exception ignored in: 0x0000021241E77168>
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line >170, in del self.CleanUp()
 File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line >147, in CleanUp self.CheckGuardSignature()
 File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line >286, in CheckGuardSignature c_void_p(self.mem_address + self.size),
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Warning (from warnings module): File ".\QuickHeal.py", line 14 AuthenticationText = appl['Dialog'].Static1.WindowText()
 DeprecationWarning: Method .WindowText() is deprecated, use .window_text() >instead.
```

---

```
from pywinauto import application
import warnings
import time
from pywinauto import keyboard

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

appl = application.Application()
appl.start(r"C:\Program Files\Seqrite\Seqrite\Quickup.exe")
appl['Dialog'].NextButton.click_input()
appl['Dialog']['RadioButton3'].click_input()
appl['Dialog']['Edit'].SetText(r"\\10.10.93.167\QHUpdates")
appl['Dialog'].NextButton.click_input()
AuthenticationText = appl['Dialog'].Static1.WindowText()
'''text ="Quick Update module requires the definition file to upgrade 
Seqrite. Specify the location which contains the definition file"
updateSuccessfully = "up-to-date"
while text !=AuthenticationText:
    AuthenticationText = appl['Dialog'].Static1.WindowText()'''
updateSuccessfully = "up-to-date"
if updateSuccessfully in AuthenticationText:

   appl['Dialog'].FinishButton.click_input()

   appl = application.Application()
   appl.start(r"C:\Program Files\Seqrite\Seqrite\Scanner.exe")
   appl['Dialog']["ScanButton"].click_input()
   appl['Dialog']["Button 11"].click_input()
   time.sleep(30)

   appl.start(r"C:\Program Files\Seqrite\Seqrite\Scanner.exe")
   appl['Dialog']['ToolsButton'].click_input()
   appl['Dialog']['Launch Antimalware'].click_input()
   appl['Dialog']['Button15'].click_input()
   time.sleep(20)
   keyboard.send_keys("{ENTER}")


   Report = appl['Dialog']['ReportsButton']
   Report.click_input()
   appl['Dialog']['Button1ListView'].click_input("HOME")
   appl['Dialog']['Detailsbutton'].click_input()
   appl['Dialog']['Save AsButton '].click_input()

   appl['Save As']["Edit0"].set_edit_text(r"D:\Scan Report.txt")
   appl['Save As']["SaveButton"].click_input()
   appl['dialog'].close()

   appl['dialog']['Button9'].type_keys("{HOME}{DOWN 6}{ENTER}")
   appl['Dialog']['Button1ListView'].click_input("HOME")
   appl['Dialog']['Detailsbutton'].click_input()
   appl['Dialog']['Save AsButton '].click_input()
   appl['Save As']["Edit0"].set_edit_text(r"D:\Quick Update Report.txt")
   appl['Save As']["SaveButton"].click_input()
   appl['dialog'].close()

   appl['dialog']['Button9'].type_keys("{HOME}{DOWN 11}{ENTER}")
   appl['Dialog']['Button1ListView'].click_input("HOME")
   appl['Dialog']['Detailsbutton'].click_input()
   appl['Dialog']['Save AsButton '].click_input()
   appl['Save As']["Edit0"].set_edit_text(r"D:\AntiMalware Report.txt")
   appl['Save As']["SaveButton"].click_input()
   appl['dialog'].close()
```

---

```
Exception ignored in: <function RemoteMemoryBlock.__del__ at 0x000001A7ED0B80D8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line 170, in __del__
    self.CleanUp()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line 147, in CleanUp
    self.CheckGuardSignature()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line 286, in CheckGuardSignature
    c_void_p(self.mem_address + self.size),
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: it always shows while running code... Any suggesstion why is it so.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more information on what you did and where it exactly failed. This will help understanding you problem. If you want to add more information to your question please edit the question instead of writing a comment.

Comment: The traceback output looks not full. Which line exactly fails?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I have Posted the full error while running the code.  And can u explain how to click the button using automation ID generated by inspect.exe tool

Comment: Hmm... This is Anitvirus software, right? That might be interesting case if the antivirus protects itself by memory manipulations. Maybe it detects GUI text retrieval as dangerous action. Hope I can try to reproduce it on trial version.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov ok waiting..

Comment: @VasilyRyabov any update ???  or can you suggest any automation tool ???

Comment: Sorry, I'm too overloaded. No chance to take a look till this summer. If it will be still actual, please remind me in a few months.

Comment: ok , I will remind :)